# time to create a bot for second life using linden scripting language?

Tags: linden-scripting-language

how much time does it take to create a simple dance performing bot in second life using Linden Scripting Language ?? , i have no prior knowledge of lsl , but i know various object oriented and event driven programming languages .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's pretty simple to animate avatar: you'll need a dance animation (those are pretty easy to find, or you could [create your own](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/How_to_create_animations)), put it in a prim (which is basic building object in SL), and then create a simple script which first requests permission to animate desired avatar:

```
llRequestPermissions(agent_key, PERMISSION_TRIGGER_ANIMATION);
```

You receive response in run_time_permissions event and trigger your animation by name:

```
run_time_permissions(integer param) 
{
    llStartAnimation("my animation");
}
```

Those are the essentials; you'll probably want to request permissions when an avatar touches your object, and stop animation on second touch... or you could request for permissions for each avatar which is in certain range.

As for the "bot" part, Second Life viewer code is open source; if you don't want to build it yourself, there are several customizable bots available. Or you could simply run an official SL viewer and leave it on; there is a way to [run several instances of SL viewer](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Help%3aRunning_multiple_instances_of_the_Second_Life_client) at the same time. It all depends on what exactly you need it for.

Official LSL portal can be found [here](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/LSL_Portal), though I prefer slightly outdated [LSL wiki](http://lslwiki.net/lslwiki/wakka.php?wakka=HomePage).

Comment: thanks for the reply , it's pretty clear . but can't i host my bot on some website , as essentially it's just a script .

Comment: how can i give commands to my bots from typing in to a particular channel in local chat from another avatar ?? For ex: i want to activate sit function when in particular channel of local chat "sit" command is given .

Comment: The bot needs to connet to SL; you can have bot interface through the website but the bot itself is a piece of code which has to run somewhere. Google it for more details, I didn't use one so I can't offer much advice there. As for giving commands, typing "/1 sit" in chat in SL client will say "sit" on channel 1. Channel 0 is chat channel heard by nearby avatars, so saying "/0 blah" is the same as saying just "blah".

Comment: this answer was accepted, but that may be because there were very few people answering lsl questions eight years ago. the original question, being about making an object dance, which cannot be done using an externally automated avatar.

Answer (score 0):

Slight language mismatch: To make an *object* perform a dance is currently known as **"puppetry"** in a SecondLife context. The term **"bot"** currently means control of an avatar by an external script api.

Anyway in one instance, it took me about two hours to write, when I did one for a teddy bear a few weeks back, but that was after learning alot from taking apart some old ones, and i never did finish making the dance, it just waggles the legs or hugs with the arms, but the script is capable for however many steps and parts you can cram in memory.

Puppetry of objects has not improved much in the past decade. It is highly restricted by movement update rates and script limitations. Movement is often delayed under server load and the client doesn't always get updates, which produces pauses and skips in varying measure. Scripts have a maximum size of 64k which should be plenty but in actuality runs out fast with the convolutions necessary in lsl. Moving each linked prim in an object seperately used to need a script in each prim, until new fuctions were introduced to apply attributes by linknumber, still many objects use old scripts which may never be updated. Laggy puppets make for a pitiful show, but most users would not know how to identify a good puppetry script.

The popular way to start making a puppet script is to find an older open source puppet script online, and update it to work from one script. Some archane versions are given as 'master' and 'slave' scripts which need to be merged placing the slave actions as a function into the master, changing `llMessageLinked( )` for the function name. Others use an identical script for each prim. I said popular, not the simplest or easiest, and it will never be the best.

Scripting from scratch, the active flow needs to go in a timer event with nothing else in it. Use a different state for animating if a timer is needed when waiting because it's a heavy activity and you don't need any more ifs or buts.

The most crucial task is create a loop to build parameters from a list of linknumbers, positions, and rotations into a parameter list before the [`llSetLinkPrimitiveParamsFast( )`](https://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/LlSetLinkPrimitiveParamsFast). Yes, that's what they called it because it's a heavy list based function, you may just call it SLPPF inworld but not in the script. Because SLPPF requires the call to have certain constants for each parameter, the parameter list for each step will need to include `PRIM_LINK_TARGET, linknumber, PRIM_POS, position, PRIM_ROT, rotation` for each linked part in the animation step.

Here's an example of putting a list of a single puppetry step into SLPPF.

```
list parameters;
integer index;
while ( index < total ) { // total number of elements in each list
  parameters += [
    PRIM_LINK_TARGET, llList2Integer( currentstep, index ),
    PRIM_POS, llList2Vector( currentstep, index+1 ),
    PRIM_ROT, llList2Rotation( currentstep, index+2 )
  ];
  index += 3;
}
llSetLinkPrimitiveParamsFast( 0, parameters );
```

How you create your currentstep list is another matter but the smoothest movement over many linked parts will only be possible if the script isn't moving lists around. So if running the timer at 0.2 seconds isn't any improvement over 0.3, it's because you've told lsl to shovel too many lists. This loop with three list calls may handle about 20 links at 0.1 seconds if the weather's good.

That's actually the worst of it over, just be careful of memory if cramming too many step lists into memory at once. Oh and if your object just vanishes completely, it's going to be hanging around near `<0,0,0>` because a `1` landed in the `PRIM_LINK_TARGET` hole.